# iPhone ＆ FileAPI で日本語タイトルのファイルを利用する方法

Tags: javascript, html5, iphone

- 環境

  - iPhone6
  - UserAgent: Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 10_1_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/602.2.14 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/10.0 Mobile/14B150 Safari/602.1

iPhone からファイルアップロードを利用するため FileAPI を利用しています。 PC上、iPhone から共に日本語を**ファイル名**に含まないファイルのアップロードは問題ないのですが、iPhoneから日本語を**ファイル名**に含むファイルをアップロードしようとするとうまく行きません。

調べてみると File API でファイルを選択(フォトライブラリやDropboxから)した時点で fileサイズが0となり、アップロードの前段階で失敗しているようです(以下で動作確認できます)。

http://codepen.io/snufkon/pen/mOPYmE

```js
function handleFileSelect(e) {
  var targetFile = e.target.files[0];

  console.log("name: ", targetFile.name);
  console.log("size: ", targetFile.size);
  console.log(targetFile);
  var result = "<p>name: " + targetFile.name + "</p>";
  result += "<p>size: " + targetFile.size + "</p>";

  document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = result;
}

document.getElementById("file").addEventListener("change", handleFileSelect, false);
```

```html
<input id="file" type="file">
<div id="result"></div>
```

これはバグ？として既知の問題なのでしょうか？また、回避方法などありましたら教えていただけないでしょうか？

以上、よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

本日(4/18)、Safariで日本語ファイル名をアップロードできることを確認しました。
iOS 10.3.1です。ただ、iOS 9.3.2でも正常にアップロードできてます。
今年(2017)の2月下旬？まではアップロードできなかったことを確認しているのですが・・・。
なぜ、アップロードできるようになったか不明です。

Comment: 情報ありがとうございます。自分も iPhone6& iOS 10.3.1 でアップロードの段階で file サイズが 0 になってしまう問題が解決していることを確認できました。

Answer (score 1):

すみません、回答ではないのですが全く同じ問題にぶつかっています。

回避方法とは違うかもしれませんが、iOSのドルフィンブラウザを利用すれば正常にアップロードされることを確認しております。(ファイルサイズやファイル名の文字化けも正常値です。)

以下、私の認識ですが・・・。（間違っているかもしれません。）
・おそらく文字コードが自動判別できるブラウザだと正常動作するのでは？
・Dropbox(GoogleDrive,OneDrive)からiOSのTemp?領域にダウンロードする際にISO-8859-1で処理されているのでは？

解決方法ではなくすみません。私も同様に困っていたので記述させて頂きました。